# Spring Integration migration issue with aggregator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I'm moving my legacy app from Spring Integration (SI) from 4.3.8 to 5.2.6. (And i use Spring Boot ver #2.2.7) In some of my routes i have the following chain:

```
<int:chain id="answersChain" input-channel="answersChannel">
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="route" expression="@config.get(payload.name)"
                        type="com.model.Route"/>
        </int:header-enricher>
        <int:aggregator discard-channel="unmatchedAnswersChannel"
                        group-timeout-expression="size() ge 2 ? 0 : one.headers['route']?.timeout"
                        expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
                        send-partial-result-on-expiry="false"
                        correlation-strategy-expression="payload.correlKey"
                        release-strategy-expression="size() == 2 and !#this[1].payload.sysReply"
                        expression="#this[1]"
        />
        <int:router expression="headers['route'].source.channelName"/>
</int:chain>
```

Actually the code and SI layouts are covered with unit-test. Running unit-test against version 4.3.8 is fine. But running the same test against SI version 5.2.6 fails. It seems that last 'int:router' is not called at all. At least i can't see it was called in logs as i saw it running under SI ver. 4.3.8. When unit test fails - nothing is dropped into discard-channel. It seems that this aggregator behaves itself like a black hole.

I need to clarify two questions:

1. Are there any critical update/bugs in SI ver. 5.2.6 causing the issue?
2. How can i debug my layout? so far i use different stubs under debug but maybe there are some more convinient ways?

Thanks in advance for any assist

Comment: I can't think of any changes off the top of my head that would affect this; turn on DEBUG logging and follow the message flow, aggregator behavior to see what's happening.

Comment: There were 3 minor releases in between, so definitely there might be a change, but it is hard right now to figure out it. It sounds more like you exit from your test earlier than messages are laded in the `unmatchedAnswersChannel`. Maybe better to give us a simple project to let us to play and reproduce. Nothing looks suspicious in your configuration to be honest...

Comment: Thanx for your suggestions. Gary, can you give me some ideas about how to enable DEBUG mode for sure? It seems that my tries to turn it on were useless. Artem, let me try to debug it at 1st step. Hope debugging will help. Alone w/ your idea about 'too fast unit-test')

Comment: But from the other side my test check the message arrives in some specific channel.Not the discard-channel one. In SI ver# 4.3.8 the message was caught in proper channel. Now it is being lost somewhere

Comment: Go to your logging configuration and provide a `debug` level for `org.springframework.integration` category. This way you’ll see how messages are traveling through components.

Answer (score 0):

Under 'trace' logging i see that issue is somewhere else in my app. Actually there is no claims so far to the SI aggregator logic.